# Tryin to retrieve HTML element value in C# but stuck on error : "does not exist in the current context."

Tags: javascript, c#, html, razor

I am trying to retrieve the value of an html element in C# by first adding an html element :

```
input type="text" id="txtName" name="Name" value="Email" runat="server" />
```

and then trying to point to it in C# using:

```
string email = txtName.Value;
```

**But I am getting an error:** The name "txtName" does not exist in the current context.

Please note that my file is .cshtml so I am writing both parts of code in the same file.

Comment: Why are you trying to do that? You cannot access the value that the user will type in once he/she sees the page, because that page still needs to be sent.

Comment: What are you trying to do? If this is for client side work, you'll want to use javascript most likely. For server-side you'll use C# in the appropriate controller method. Looks like you're trying to write winforms code in MVC.

Comment: I have several <a href="#"> tags and I want to know which one the user clicked to load a modal popup displaying a highchart accordingly. I tried adding an id attribute for the "a" element and I could retrieve it using jquery but I want to have it in my C# part of code.

Comment: In ASP.NET MVC, this is something you'd be much better off doing in javascript. If you want to do something like this in C# with MVC, you'll need to POST the value via AJAX to a controller and then use the response to return your HTML for your modal and then display it via javascript. The runat attribute on your input does not do anything in ASP.NET MVC or Razor.

Comment: Thank you, sounds good. But can I get the response in the C# part of the code? I think I succeeded in writing the POST part but I am facing a little bit difficulties in reading what is posted.
The POST part:
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Home/AjaxMethod",
        data: 'ID',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",   
    });